# How to create a function which will retrieve year, based on a certain logic

Tags: db2, stored-functions

I need to create a function in DB2 which will retrieve year from the current date, based on a certain logic

- If the number of the month of the current date is smaller and equal than 6 (=any month prior to June) then the previous year is the ‘reference year’
- Else if the number of the month of the current date is larger than 6 (=any month after June!) then the current year is the ‘reference year’.

Examples:

- The reference year for date ‘4/9/2019’ is 2018 , since 4 <= 6
- The reference year for date ‘9/3/2019’ is 2019, since 9 > 6

Below is an example for the implementation for SQL Server:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getReferenceYear()  
 RETURNS int   
 AS   

 BEGIN  
 DECLARE @ret int;  
 SELECT @ret = MONTH(GETDATE())

  IF (@ret <= 6)   
    SET @ret = (YEAR(GETDATE()) -1); 
    Else 
    SET @ret = (YEAR(GETDATE()) ); 
   RETURN @ret;  
 END;
```

**I need the same in db2.**

Below is what I have tried

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getReferenceYear()  
 RETURNS INT
 BEGIN ATOMIC

 DECLARE _month INT;
 DECLARE _year INT;

  SET _month = SELECT MONTH (current timestamp)  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 

  if(_month<=6)
  SET _year = (SELECT YEAR (current timestamp)  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) -1
  ELSE
  SET _year = (SELECT YEAR (current timestamp)  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1)

 RETURN _year
END
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you write an udf with the above logic in db2?

Comment: @data_henrik, can you please help me

Comment: Side note: `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` _may_ yield a different value each time it's called (Depend on a few things).  You'd be better off working with a stored value, or the results of such a query could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do in in Db2-LUW:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION dbo.getReferenceYear()  
 RETURNS INT
 BEGIN ATOMIC

  declare v_nowts timestamp default current timestamp;
  declare v_year int;

  set v_year= year(v_nowts);
  if ( month(v_nowts) <= 6 ) THEN
     SET v_year = v_year -1;
  END IF;
  RETURN v_year ;
END
```

Comment: I am getting an error of  `function sequence error`

Comment: @mao...is there any alternative?

Comment: What operating-system runs your Db2-SERVER (z/os  , i-series , linux/unix/windows),   and also what version is your Db2?

Comment: After replacing the `or replace`, it got executed properly. Now, can you help me how i can verify it on db2 ???

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getReferenceYear()  
 RETURNS INT
 as
 BEGIN     
 DECLARE @month INT,@year INT;    
  SET @month = SELECT MONTH (ColumnName)  FROM TableName    
  if(_month<=6)
  SET @year = (SELECT YEAR (ColumnName)  FROM TableName -1)
  ELSE
  SET @year = (SELECT YEAR (ColumnName)  FROM TableName)    
 RETURN @year
END
```

Or if you don't have any column for the date and if you want to apply the same logic for the current date, then-

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getReferenceYear()  
  RETURNS INT
  as
  BEGIN 
  DECLARE @month INT,@year INT;
   SET @month =( SELECT MONTH (GETDATE())  )      
   if(@month<=6)
   SET @year = (SELECT YEAR (GETDATE())-1)  
   ELSE
   SET @year = (SELECT YEAR (GETDATE()) )
  RETURN @year
  END
```

Comment: I want it in db2, not in sql server

Comment: can you please provide this udf in db2

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION getReferenceYear()  
RETURNS SMALLINT
RETURN YEAR(CURRENT DATE) - CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT DATE) <= 6 then 1 ELSE 0 END
```